# Powershell Exceptions/Registry Key

Tags: sql-server, exception, powershell, registrykey

I have a script - with its according module - that lists from SQL all the instances from different Servers within the company I'm interning for.
This script works in another host machine but not in mine.
I get a `MethodInvocationException` and the error message is the following:

```
Exception calling "OpenSubKey" with "1" argument(s): "Requested registry access is not allowed."
```

The error comes from a file inside a module, not from the actual script.

I know its very general and Im not allowed to show the code, but any guidlines/tips or heads up on how to solve it? I tried playing around with something called registry key, but I'm not sure how it works.

Help please?

Comment: Your issue is that the module is attempting to open a registry key (one of the folder icons you see when you launch regedit) and you don't have permissions to access that key. You need to find the registry key that it cannot read, and then give yourself access (or ask a network administrator too, depending on your organization). One thing though - have you tried launching powershell as an administrator? (Right-click on the powershell icon and click "Run as administrator")

Comment: @RB. yes i always run it as an admin. I talked about this to the senior DBA and he said that users have access to the HKEY_CURRENT_USER key by default. I added that key to one of the files in the module, but nothing seems to change. I added it as so: $regKey= $reg.OpenSubKey( "HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\\Microsoft\\Microsoft SQL Server\\Instance Names\\SQL" )

Comment: You'll need to determine exactly which key is the one you are getting "access denied" for, using one of the 2 methods I outlined in my answer - otherwise you are pretty much shooting in the dark...

Comment: @RB. cool, but it doesnt quite solve my problem. Do you know what could be wrong with the script to get this problem? I've tried using both reg keys (current user and local machine) which are apparently default. None work.

Comment: Well, if you can access the two keys you have tried, the issue must be with a 3rd that you haven't tried! Use Process Monitor, or inspect the $Error object to find out which. The script itself is not the cause - it's a permissions issue...

Comment: @RB. yeah i kinda figured it was a permission issue, because this works on other hosts. Im sorry but i dont seem to understand what you mean by third key? So in the script i only used the local machine key. What role does a third key play in here? I thought i only had to worry about the keys used in the script :/ btw many thanks for the help!

Comment: HKLM and HKCU are both "hives", not "keys". A key in registry terms is any folder in the registry - e.g. HKLM:\Software\Microsoft\Windows. Without knowing what the actual key you are trying to access is, you don't know what to change the permissions on. Note that to change the permissions you can use regedit - right click on the key, and select "Permissions".

Comment: @RB.Yup i changed the permissions before posting this question. The $Error object however, seems to be very useful. I think the issue is that the keys in my local machine are not the same as the keys in someone else's machine (that someone else sent me this script). Thanks anyways :D

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Process Monitor](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-gb/sysinternals/bb896645.aspx) to view all the registry accesses. This will show the one for which access is denied, and from there you can grant yourself the necessary access.

You will need to set suitable filters or you will be overwhelmed by the number of events! I would suggest the following:

- Path: Operation is "RegOpenKey"
- Result: is "Access Denied"

---

### Option 2

Execute the command in PowerShell, then execute the following command:

```
$> $Error[0]
```

This should hopefully print something like the following, which will tell you the key it failed on:

```
dir : Requested registry access is not allowed.
At line:1 char:1
+ dir
+ ~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : PermissionDenied: (HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SECURITY:String) [Get-ChildItem], SecurityException
+ FullyQualifiedErrorId : System.Security.SecurityException,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.GetChildItemCommand
```